# Temperature distribution through the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

A metal rod of length $L = 1$ is kept at constant temperatures at the two ends
$u(x = 0, t) = u(x = 1, t) = 0$ and is heated with a constant heat source S(x) concentrated in the
middle $(S(x) = 1$ for $0.4 ≤ x < 0.6$ and $S(x) = 0$ elsewhere). The temperature distribution u(x, t)
satisfies the heat equation:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=D\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + S(x)
$$

where D = 1 is the heat diffusion coefficient. The initial condition is $u(x, t = 0) = 0$ (i.e. there is a constant temperature before the heat source is switched on). After a certain time the solution $u(x, t)$ converges towards a time-independent stationary temperature distribution $u_s(x)$. Find an expression for $u_s(x)$.

I solved $u(x) = c_1\cdot x$ for the first domain [0,0.4] and I solved $u(x) = c_3(1-x) $ for the third domain [0.6,1]. Then I integrate $u'' +1=0$ and get $u=-\frac12 x^2 +c_5\cdot x +c_6$, however, I don't know how to find the unknown integration variable.

Comment: I know $c_1 = 0$ because $u_s(1,t) = 0$. I am not sure how to get $c_5$ and $c_6$. I think it has to do with IC.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I am still wondering about this question. It would be great if you could post the answer if you have it!